# Nicescroll touchbehavior bug in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a very basic nicescroll implementation like this:

```
 <script src="../javascript/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../javascript/jquery.nicescroll3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#scrolldiv").niceScroll({touchbehavior:true});
     });
 </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" class="input-form" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="thescriptmanager" runat="server"/>
        <div id="scrolldiv" style="height:200px;width:200px;">
            ..long content..
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The problem is that the "throw" ability no longer works in Chrome 24 (dragging and releasing to gradually ease to a stop.)  Instead it abruptly halts.  It used to work when I started development, I have since upgraded to jquery 1.8 and nicescroll 3.0.  It works properly in IE, FF, and Safari.  I have tried rebooting and reinstalling Chrome to no avail.  Does anyone else experience this or know what could be going on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, I was able to solve this by uninstalling Chrome, rebooting, then reinstalling.  Reinstalling over the top did not work!